# Show the sidebar even on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, sidebar

I'm making a documentation page here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ic2wNhXQSGp9sH1cV0BF?p=preview

```
<div class="doc-sidebar col-md-3 col-12 order-0 d-none d-md-flex">
    <div id="doc-nav" class="doc-nav">
        <nav id="doc-menu" class="nav doc-menu flex-column sticky">
            <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#download-section">Download</a>
            <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#installation-section">Installation</a>
            <nav class="doc-sub-menu nav flex-column">
                <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#step1">Step One</a>
                <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#step2">Step Two</a>
                <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#step3">Step Three</a>
            </nav><!--//nav-->
        </nav><!--//doc-menu-->
    </div>
</div><!--//doc-sidebar-->
```

Currently, the sidebar disappears when the page is displayed on mobile, which is not what I want. I want to keep the sidebar even on mobile, and let the rectangular of the sidebar overlay the text under it. For example, like the following sidebar:

[image]

Does anyone know how to change the code to achieve this? Then, I will add a trigger button on mobile to show/hide the sidebar by JSQuery (I know how to do this).

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help. This is not the final appearance but showing how to use `navbar`.

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
  position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease;
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
    left: -100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.show {
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 project documentation theme for developers</title>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- FontAwesome JS -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-DJ25uNYET2XCl5ZF++U8eNxPWqcKohUUBUpKGlNLMchM7q4Wjg2CUpjHLaL8yYPH" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Global CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link id="theme-style" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>

<body class="body-green">
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <!-- ******Header****** -->
    <div class="doc-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="doc-header" class="doc-header text-center">
          <h1 class="doc-title"><i class="icon fa fa-paper-plane"></i> 10 Studio</h1>
          <div class="meta"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Last updated: July 18th, 2018</div>
        </div>
        <!--//doc-header-->
        <div class="doc-body row">
          <div class="doc-content col-md-9 col-12 order-1">
            <div class="content-inner">
              <section id="download-section" class="doc-section">
                <h2 class="section-title">Download</h2>
                <div class="section-block">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec imperdiet turpis. Curabitur aliquet pulvinar ultrices. Etiam at posuere leo. Proin ultrices ex et dapibus feugiat <a href="#">link example</a> aenean purus leo, faucibus
                    at elit vel, aliquet scelerisque dui. Etiam quis elit euismod, imperdiet augue sit amet, imperdiet odio. Aenean sem erat, hendrerit eu gravida id, dignissim ut ante. Nam consequat porttitor libero euismod congue.
                  </p>
                  <a href="https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/bootstrap-templates/startup/prettydocs-free-bootstrap-theme-for-developers-and-startups/" class="btn btn-green" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download PrettyDocs</a>
                </div>
              </section>
              <!--//doc-section-->
              <section id="installation-section" class="doc-section">
                <h2 class="section-title">Installation</h2>
                <div id="step1" class="section-block">
                  <h3 class="block-title">Step One</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis.
                  </p>
                  <div class="code-block">
                    <h6>Default code example:</h6>
                    <p><code>bower install &lt;package&gt;</code></p>
                    <p><code>npm install &lt;package&gt;</code></p>
                  </div>
                  <!--//code-block-->
                </div>
                <!--//section-block-->
                <div id="step2" class="section-block">
                  <h3 class="block-title">Step Two</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
                  </p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                      <h6>Un-ordered list example</h6>
                      <ul class="list">
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris.</li>
                        <li>Ultricies eget vel aliquam libero.
                          <ul>
                            <li>Turpis pulvinar</li>
                            <li>Feugiat scelerisque</li>
                            <li>Ut tincidunt</li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi.</li>
                        <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                      <h6>Ordered list example</h6>
                      <ol class="list">
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris.</li>
                        <li>Ultricies eget vel aliquam libero.
                          <ul>
                            <li>Turpis pulvinar</li>
                            <li>Feugiat scelerisque</li>
                            <li>Ut tincidunt</li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi.</li>
                        <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id.</li>
                      </ol>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--//row-->
                </div>
                <!--//section-block-->
                <div id="step3" class="section-block">
                  <h3 class="block-title">Step Three</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <!--//section-block-->
              </section>
              <!--//doc-section-->


              </section>
              <!--//doc-section-->
            </div>
            <!--//content-inner-->
          </div>
          <!--//doc-content-->

          <nav class="navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
              <div class="list-group">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
                  Cras justo odio
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" disabled>Vestibulum at
                  eros</button>
              </div>

              <!-- <nav id="doc-menu" class="nav doc-menu flex-column sticky">
                <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#download-section">Download</a>
                <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#installation-section">Installation</a>
                <nav class="doc-sub-menu nav flex-column">
                  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#step1">Step One</a>
                  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#step2">Step Two</a>
                  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#step3">Step Three</a>
                </nav>
          </nav> -->

            </div>

          </nav>

          <!--//doc-sidebar-->
        </div>
        <!--//doc-body-->
      </div>
      <!--//container-->
    </div>
    <!--//doc-wrapper-->

  </div>
  <!--//page-wrapper-->


  <!-- Main Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="stickyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you... You show how to show a sidebar from the top, please keep it and i will also look for a sidebar from left.

Answer (score 0):

Here the snippet to make a Navbar Vertical and display on a mobile device:-

https://jsfiddle.net/nr1g5sLd/

Navbar Code:-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light  flex-column align-items-start">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column w-100 align-items-start">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
```

Kindly notice 2 classes:- 1)  flex-column 2) align-items-start.

For Further Reference. You can read about flex here:-
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/